# Verify drl file when compiling with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, drools

First, I've attempted to use the kie-maven-plugin in the project parent:

```
<groupId>org.kie</groupId>
<artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>6.1.0.Final</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
```

but after further reading it doesn't sound like it actually precompiles the rules before placing them in the jar (and I don't see any sign of it doing so).

I also see that there is a drools verifier, however it seems that this only works to verify drl files within Java.

Is there a good way to compile / verify a drl file in a Maven build so that I don't deploy and run the webservice only to find that there is a typo in the drl file?

I'm currently using Eclipse Kepler w/ the Drools plugins, Maven 3.x and Drools 6.0.1.

Comment: I would generally say, just write a test in JUnit (other test frameworks are available) which loads your DRL into a knowledge base. Even without writing tests of the functionality, you will get confirmation that at least it compiles.

Comment: I didn't think of that but that's a solution that could work if I cannot figure out how to get maven to compile.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that you forgot to specify the packaging as "kjar". If that is the case, the plugin won't be executed during the Maven build. Simply add `<packaging>kjar</packaging>` into you pom.xml.

Please see the example usage of the kie-maven-plugin: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/kie-maven-plugin-example/pom.xml

To best of my knowledge the kie-maven-plugin only verifies that the resources can be compiled. Running Drools verifier is not part of the execution.

If you are already using the "kjar" packaging, please post the entire pom.xml, otherwise it is hard to guess what is actually causing the described behavior.

Comment: You were correct in that I didn't have the <packaging>kjar</packaging> in the pom (we were using pom packaging), however after updating that, I'm still able to get a successful build with an invalid drl file.  My parent pom contains everyting from the example you posted.

Comment: Using the "pom" packaging will definitely won't work as you are actually creating an ordinary jar file (with bit of Drools specific stuff there). Could you post your (simplified) poms somewhere? Or at least output of the Maven run?